# Как правильно обработать кадры с камеры ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, камера

Как мне стало известно, чтобы сконверировать кадры с камеры в картинку нужно использовать метод

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Также мне стало известно, что явно вызвать его не получиться, только через делегат и через очередь. Вот это то и не понятно. К примеру, [код от эппл](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html) я не знаю как встроить в проект, чтобы заработал и можно было поиграться с обработкой изображения.
Из ряда проектов на гитхабе я увидел, что данный метод иногда только объявляют в заголовочном файле (`.h`), без реализации. (Вообще в голове не укладывается).

**Вопрос:** 
Как правильно использовать данный метод? В каком файле правильно писать очередь, а в каком сам метод? Если есть где-то в сети короткий проект, в котором этот метод отрабатывает - дайте ссылку пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что именно не так с мануалом от эппла? Уберите лишние release и удалите устаревшое   output.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 15);

```
 -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer

   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

    //Метод вызывается при записи данных с камеры в буфер 

    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    //Преобразовывать полученный буфер в картинку



   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
              ^{
                  self.imageView.image = [self applyMonoChromeWithRedColor:image];

                  //Применить какие-либо эффекты к изображению,
                 // фильтр, к примеру, и добавить на экран
              });
}
```

При инициализации session вы указываете делегата, в классе делегата и описывайте метод. Вообще сессия здесь работает в два потока, по сути, в input вы добавляете камеру, в output ваш класс-обработчик в качестве делегата. [простой пример с наложением синего фильтра](https://yadi.sk/d/T3Vrmxx9ssW5v)

Comment: За пример большое спасибо. Работает, метод отрабатывает, код почти ясен. Будет здорово если вы далеко не уйдёте. В комментариях у меня могут возникнуть к вам, как к специалисту вопросы.

Comment: а скажите пожалуйста, почему метод 

`-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBufferfromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{`

 помещается только в файл - реализацию? Почему он не присутствует в заголовке (.h)?

Comment: Ну, можно добавить, только зачем? Объявлять в заголовочном файле методы, имеет смысл, когда, к примеру, вам нужно будет к ним обратиться из другого класса.

Comment: то есть, можно все методы не помещать в `h`, если программа записана одним классом? И ничего не поломается?

Comment: Можно не объявлять, не поломается. В objective, если я не ошибаюсь, приватные методы как в плюсах отсутствуют, (property на public/private разделить еще можно), поэтому методы раскидываете по .h и .m в по необходимости, как-то так.